# toggle div placed inside another div on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

looking to create a quick view tab when a customer hovers over a product.

ive pretty much got it sorted but my problem is as soon as your mouse moved onto the quick view div button, the button starts to fade away as it technically moved off the trigger div. how do i keep it on??

heres the jquery im using

```
    $("#cat_product").hover(
    function () {
        $(".quickview").fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(".quickview").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

heres the fiddle im using to test things out - https://jsfiddle.net/a0j96wyc/

Comment: can you try this?? https://jsfiddle.net/a0j96wyc/1/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a hover event for `.quickview`, as well. When you hover off of `#cat_product` and over `.quickview`, the hover event for `.quickview` takes over and prevents the button from fading out.

Since the button is completely contained by `#cat_product`, I have not included a "hover off" event for `.quickview`. You won't ever be hovering off of the button without hovering over `#cat_product`.

Also, I'm using [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the animation queue and prevent fade flickers.

```js
$("#cat_product").hover(
  function () {$(".quickview").stop(true,true).fadeIn();},
  function () {$(".quickview").fadeOut();}
);

$(".quickview").hover(
  function () {$(this).stop(true, true).show(0);}
);
```

```css
.quickview {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/Bedroom+Furniture/Chest+of+Drawers/1567493/ViewProduct/" class="normal_text" style="text-decoration:none">

  <div id="cat_product" style="width:250px; border:1px solid #000">

    <div class="options_overlay_cat">
      <div style='text-align:center'>
        <div style="height:170px">

          <img class="lazy" src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/?src=img-1567493.jpg&amp;w=170" data-original="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/?src=img-1567493.jpg&amp;w=170" title="Mark Webster MWG017 Geo 6 Drawer Tallboy" border="0" style="display: inline;">
          <noscript>&lt;img src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/?src=img-1567493.jpg&amp;w=170"&gt;</noscript>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:left; padding:20px 8px 20px 8px"><b><font style="font-size:14px; color:#00CC00">Geo</font></b>
          <br><font style="font-size:13px">6 Drawer Tallboy</font>
          <br>

          <div style="padding-top:8px;">
            <div style="float:left"><font class="small_black_text">Was <strike>£579</strike></font>
              <br><font style=" color:#C50132" class="product_price_18">£489</font>
            </div>
            <div style="padding:5px; background-color:#C50132; margin-top:5px; color:white; float:right"><b>SAVE £90<b></b></b>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>

          <div style="height:20px;padding-top:10px;">
            <div>
              <div style="float:left; width:14px; height:14px; border:1px solid #999999; margin-left:3px;">
                <img src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/finishes/?src=geo_lacquered.jpg&amp;w=14" title="Lacquered" border="0">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='quick' class='quickview hidden' style="position:absolute; margin: -270px 0px 0px 80px; height:48px; width:108px">
    <a href="//www.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/modules/quickview/index.php?id='.$row[0].'" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">
      <img src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/quickview_button.png" height="48" />
    </a>
  </div>
</a>
```

### Edit:

**CSS Solution**

With a minor adjustment to your HTML structure, you can use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate opacity and avoid using JavaScript altogether. Example below:

```css
.quickview {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
div#cat_product:hover div.quickview {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/Bedroom+Furniture/Chest+of+Drawers/1567493/ViewProduct/" class="normal_text" style="text-decoration:none">

  <div id="cat_product" style="width:250px; border:1px solid #000">

    <div class="options_overlay_cat">
      <div style='text-align:center'>
        <div style="height:170px">

          <img class="lazy" src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/?src=img-1567493.jpg&amp;w=170" data-original="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/?src=img-1567493.jpg&amp;w=170" title="Mark Webster MWG017 Geo 6 Drawer Tallboy" border="0" style="display: inline;">
          <noscript>&lt;img src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/?src=img-1567493.jpg&amp;w=170"&gt;</noscript>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:left; padding:20px 8px 20px 8px"><b><font style="font-size:14px; color:#00CC00">Geo</font></b>
          <br><font style="font-size:13px">6 Drawer Tallboy</font>
          <br>

          <div style="padding-top:8px;">
            <div style="float:left"><font class="small_black_text">Was <strike>£579</strike></font>
              <br><font style=" color:#C50132" class="product_price_18">£489</font>
            </div>
            <div style="padding:5px; background-color:#C50132; margin-top:5px; color:white; float:right"><b>SAVE £90<b></b></b>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>

          <div style="height:20px;padding-top:10px;">
            <div>
              <div style="float:left; width:14px; height:14px; border:1px solid #999999; margin-left:3px;">
                <img src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/finishes/?src=geo_lacquered.jpg&amp;w=14" title="Lacquered" border="0">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='quick' class='quickview hidden' style="position:absolute; margin: -270px 0px 0px 80px; height:48px; width:108px">
      <a href="//www.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/modules/quickview/index.php?id='.$row[0].'" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">
        <img src="//cdn.mayfieldfurniture.co.uk/images/quickview_button.png" height="48" />
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other solution. I used `setTimeout()` and modified css for the animation.

CSS:

```
.quickview{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s linear;
}
```

JS:

```
var $quickView = $(".quickview");
var timeout = null;

$("#cat_product").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $quickView.css("opacity", 1);
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $quickView.css("opacity", 0);
        }, 50);
    }
});

$('.quickview').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/a0j96wyc/3/) is the demo.

EDIT: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/a0j96wyc/6/) is a version **without jQuery**.

Comment: thanks :)

with all the answers ive come across a new problem, the hover effect is only working on the first product but shows the quickview button on all products...

https://jsfiddle.net/a0j96wyc/7/